# Integrate function in polar coordinates sciPy

Tags: python, math, numpy, scipy, sympy

For example, I have a function, defined in polar coordinates, it may be something like this:

```
r = a*b/sqrt((b*cos(f)^2) + (a*sin(f))^2) 
# ellipse in polar coordinates,
# when center of ellipse is polus 
# and bigger axis is polar axis
# f is angle, r is distance
```

How can I find, for example,length of ellipse line in sciPy?

Great thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3):

Seems like you want to calculate an [arc length](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arc_length). If you are only looking at ellipses, the solution is [known](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Ellipse.html) and you could utilize SciPy's `scipy.special.ellipeinc()` or SymPy's `elliptic_k()`function.

If you are interested in a more general approach, the choice of your integration scheme may vary depending on the properties of your functions.